# Number of times all the numbers in an array are divisible by 2

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to get the count of number of times all the `integers` in an `array` is divisible by 2 considering only one `integer` in each step.
For example, initially if I have the `array` : `[2,4,2]` and `count = 0`

> **Step 1**

```
[1,4,2] , count=1
```

> **Step 2**

```
[1,2,2] , count=2
```

> **Step 3**

```
[1,1,2] , count=3
```

> **Step 4**

```
[1,1,1] , count=4
```

My approach to the problem is given below :

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] ar={2,4,2};
     int[] p=new int[ar.length];
     int count=0;
     for (int i=0;i<ar.length ;i++ ) {
        if(ar[i]>=1){
            ar[i]=ar[i]/2;
            count++;
        }
     }
     for (int x:ar) {
        System.out.println(x);
     }
     System.out.println("Count:"+count);

}
```

> **Output**

```
1
2
1
Count:3
```

The problem in the code given above is that the `array` is scanned only one time and I want to scan the array until all the `integers are no more divisible by 2`

Comment: "I want to scan the array until all the integers are greater than or equal to 1" - but they're already all greater than or equal to 1 from the very beginning, and they remain that way.

Comment: I have edited the question, I want the `array` simplified such that no more `integers` are divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have two issues:

1. You divide each element of the array by 2 at most one time.
2. You divide elements of the array by 2 without checking first whether or not they are divisible by 2.

You need an inner loop that would divide each array element as long as it is divisible by 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] ar={2,4,2};
     int[] p=new int[ar.length];
     int count=0;
     for (int i=0;i<ar.length ;i++ ) {
        while (ar[i] % 2 == 0 && ar[i] > 0) { // keep dividing ar[i] by 2 as long as 
                                              // it is divisible by 2
            ar[i]=ar[i]/2;
            count++;
        }
     }
     for (int x:ar) {
        System.out.println(x);
     }
     System.out.println("Count:"+count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
     for (int i=0;i<ar.length ;i++ ) {
        while(ar[i]%2==0 && ar[i]>1){
            ar[i]=ar[i]/2;
            count++;
        }
     }
```

This will suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help