# How could we get within a certain range, the maximum number of times, an int is divisible by 2

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers, int

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Strongest even number in an interval](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5d16af632cf48200254a6244). The statement is:

> A strongness of an even number is the number of times we can
>   successively divide by 2 until we reach an odd number starting with an
>   even number n.
>
> For example, if n = 12, then
>
> 12 / 2 = 6
>
> 6 / 2 = 3
>
> we divided successively 2 times and we reached 3, so the strongness of
>   12 is 2.
>
> If n = 16 then
>
> 16 / 2 = 8
>
> 8 / 2 = 4
>
> 4 / 2 = 2
>
> 2 / 2 = 1
>
> we divided successively 4 times and we reached 1, so the strongness of
>   16 is 4 Task
>
> Given a closed interval [n, m], return the even number that is the
>   strongest in the interval. If multiple solutions exist return the
>   smallest strongest even number.
>
> Note that programs must run within the alloted server time; a naive
>   solution will probably time out. Constraints
>
> 1 <= n < m <= INT_MAX Examples
>
> for the input [1, 2] return 2 (1 has strongness 0, 2 has strongness 1)
>
> for the input [5, 10] return 8 (5, 7, 9 have strongness 0; 6, 10 have
>   strongness 1; 8 has strongness 2)
>
> for the input [48, 56] return 48

First I thought to store in a map each number as a key, and the number of times it is divisible by 2, as a value:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StrongestEvenNumber {
  public static int strongestEven/**/(int n, int m) {
    System.out.println("n: "+n);
    System.out.println("m: "+m);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();    
    for(int i = n, number = 0, strongness = 0; i <= m; i++){
      for(number = i, strongness = 0; number % 2 == 0; strongness++){
        number /= 2;
      }
      map.put(i, strongness);
    }
      Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry = null;
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        if(maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0){
          maxEntry = entry;
        }
      }
      return maxEntry.getKey();
  }
}
```

However, with large numbers, it runs out of heap memory space, or execution time runs out. For example with:

```
n: 1180381085
m: 2074186600
```

Java heap space runs out.

And with:

```
n: 324243
m: 897653214
```

Execution time runs out. The execution time exceeds 16000 ms

Then I tried to just store the number which is the most times divisible by 2:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StrongestEvenNumber {
  public static int strongestEven/**/(int n, int m) {
    System.out.println("n: "+n);
    System.out.println("m: "+m);
    int maxStrongness = 0, maxNumber = 0;
    for(int i = n, number = 0, strongness = 0; i <= m; i++){
      for(number = i, strongness = 0; number % 2 == 0; strongness++){
        number /= 2;
      }
      if(strongness > maxStrongness){
        maxStrongness = strongness;
        maxNumber = i;
      }
    }
      return maxNumber;
  }
}
```

Indeed it solves the heap space difficulty, however the execution time runs out behaviour stills happening.

For example with:

```
n: 200275492
m: 1590463313
```

The execution time exceeds 16000 ms

I have also read:

- [Finding Key associated with max Value in a Java Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911174/finding-key-associated-with-max-value-in-a-java-map)
- [Get the key for the maximum value in a HashMap using Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938842/get-the-key-for-the-maximum-value-in-a-hashmap-using-collections)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589831/how-many-times-can-i-divide-a-number-by-another
- [Number of times all the numbers in an array are divisible by 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386955/number-of-times-all-the-numbers-in-an-array-are-divisible-by-2)
- [optimize code to get the number of integers within given range that are divisible by integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805004/optimize-code-to-get-the-number-of-integers-within-given-range-that-are-divisibl)

Comment: Just use a logarithm??

Comment: @Aggragoth: logarithm is a possible solution but you have to fight with *rounding errors* (`Math.log` is `double`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the **strongness** of a value `x` is `n` when `x` is represented as

```
x = k * 2**n
```

knowing this we can check all powers of `2` (i.e. `1, 2, 4, 8, ...`) if we can find any `k` such that

```
from <= k * 2**n <= to
```

**Code:**

```
private static int strongestEven(int from, int to) {
  if (to < from)
    return -1; // Or throw exception

  // best power of 2 we can insert between [to..from] as k * best
  int best = 1;

  while (true) {
    int ceiling = from / best + (from % best == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    int floor = to / best;

    if (ceiling > floor) {
      best = best / 2;

      return best * (to / best);
    }

    best *= 2;
  }
}
```

**Tests:**

```
  [ 1,   2] =>   2
  [ 5,  10] =>   8
  [48,  56] =>  48
  [80, 100] =>  96
  [97, 100] => 100
```

Finally,

```
  [1180381085, 1590463313] => 1342177280
```

we have `1342177280 == 5 * 268435456 == 5 * 2**28` so the strongest number within `[1180381085, 1590463313]` range has *strongness* `28`

Please, note, that the algorithm has `O(log(to))` *time complexity* that's why will do even if we turn all `int` into `long`

Answer (score 1):

The strongness is actually the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of the number. You can use the [java.lang.Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(int)) to get it.

And as you want to test the even numbers, you can skipp the odd numbers in your loop.

```
public class StrongestEvenNumber {

  public static int strongestEven(int n, int m) {
    int maxStrongness = 0, maxNumber = 0;
    for(int i = n%2==0?n:n+1, strongness = 0; i <= m; i=i+2){
    strongness = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i);
      if(strongness > maxStrongness){
        maxStrongness = strongness;
        maxNumber = i;
      }
    }
      return maxNumber;
  }
```

This runs in the allocated time:

```
Completed in 13190ms
```

Comment: If `m` is *large* (e.g. n = `1` and m = `1_000_000_000`) looping over `n..m` interval can be *slow*; your own demosntration take `13` seconds to complete:  `Completed in 13190ms`

Comment: OP wants to run this code on the codewars site. The duration is taken from a run on codewars, this just means the test succeeds. Your answer may run much faster but what I've posted passes witb only minor optimizations from the OP's code.